# How do I add an <a> link to an icon in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com" title="Website name">Website Link</a>
```

and

```
<i style="margin-right: 0.5em; color: #EEEEEE;" class="icon-home icon-4x"></i>
```

Can someone explain to me how I can combine these in bootstrap with font awesome icons that I am using. Do I put the `<a>` inside the `<i>` or the `<i>` inside the `<a>` or do the both need to be inside a `<div>` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the `<i>` inside the `<a>`

**For Instance,**

```
<a href="http://www.website.com" title="Website name"><i style="margin-right: 0.5em; color: #EEEEEE;" class="icon-home icon-4x"></i>Website Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but there is a line that appears under my icon when I do this :-(

Comment: That is the default `a` CSS that is being applied. You need to reset it by adding this CSS. `a{text-decoration:none; border:none;}`. Hope this helps. - @Melina

Answer (score 1):

With this, only the icon will show:

```
<i style="margin-right: 0.5em; color: #EEEEEE;" class="icon-home icon-4x"></i>
```

With this, a text link will be displayed:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com" title="Website name">Website Link</a>
```

If you want to display the text and icon with them both being a link then use the following, which puts the `i` tag inside the `a` tag:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com" title="Website name"> <i style="margin-right: 0.5em; color: #EEEEEE;" class="icon-home icon-4x"></i>Website Link</a>
```